# Will iTunes match download all my music to a new hard drive?

Tags: itunes, itunes-match, data-recovery

I've been thinking about weather to use iTunes match, but not for syncing to all devices as I'm happy with what I have on my iPhone and have iPod with all songs on.

What it would be useful for is to be able to download my library if my hard drive packs in or my computer is stolen.

Will iTunes match work in this way? will I be able to download all my songs and not just the ones purchased in iTunes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enable iTunes Match, your entire library (up to 25.000) songs will be synced with your iCloud. So all your songs are in the iCloud. You can add a device to the iCloud and by so, all your music on the new device will be synced onto the new device. That's how iTunes Match works.

If you computer/hard drive gets stolen, you buy a new one and authorize it with you iCloud, it will sync once again on your new device.

So yes, you'll be able to download all your music stored in your iCloud onto new device.

As a matter of fact, even when the original device lost it's files, the songs are still stored in iCloud.

But be aware, the limit on devices is set on 10. So make sure you haven't add 10 devices already!

**EDIT**:
Proof of this is on the [iTunes Match-page](http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you provide any support information, links etc. that states a computer counts as a device, please?

Comment: Sure, see my edit

Comment: Thanks for the edit, however one question I have on this, If the original computer loses the files, will iTunse match sync and remove the files? Lets say the hard drive gets corrupted, and the files are lost, will iTunes match scan iTunes on the computer and remove songs from the library? (This is my consideration for using iTunes match)

Comment: Ok, I just did a little test and I discovered the magic part of iTunes Match. When a file is deleted on the original computer (in my case, I had to delete it manually) iTunes is giving you the chance to delete it from iCloud too. I didn't check that option, and the song stayed in iCloud. So yes. If the original computer loses the files and the sons are uploaded to iCloud, the songs will still be available on your other devices.

Comment: and with that I have iTunes match, thanks for investigating.